# How to access certain value from between a string formatted in a particular way c#

Tags: c#, deserialization

```
 <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">m48333189002</string>
```

How do i access the value m48333189002 from between this string ?

Please help

Comment: Is this a one-off string, or part of a larger file?

Answer (score 6):

You can try parsing XML:

```
XElement.Parse(str).Value
```

Comment: `var str = @"<string xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"">m48333189002</string>";`

Comment: Nice. Never attempt to parse xml on your own with substring, splitting or regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use the string.Split method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expecting like below,

**Imports :**

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

**Code :**

```
string xmlResult = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">m48333189002</string>";    
// place the sample result into a stream
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] xmlBytes = encoding.GetBytes(xmlResult);
// create a stream from the byte array
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes);
// read and deserialize the xml
XmlTextReader respXmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(ms);
// Linq to XML to extract return value from namespace decorated
// return XML string
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(respXmlRdr);
string Result = xDoc.Root.Value;
Console.WriteLine(Result);
```